# Свой провайдер цен Bitrix

Tags: php, битрикс

При добавлении в корзину использую код:

```
$item->setFields([
'QUANTITY' => $addBasketQuantity,
'CURRENCY' => \Bitrix\Currency\CurrencyManager::getBaseCurrency(),
'LID' => $_GET["site_id"],
"PRODUCT_PROVIDER_CLASS" => "Bitrix\Catalog\Product\CostumeCatalogProvider",
"CATALOG_XML_ID" => $arNextElement["IBLOCK_EXTERNAL_ID"],
"PRODUCT_XML_ID" => $arNextElement["EXTERNAL_ID"]
]);
```

После чего создал свой провайдер цены `CostumeCatalogProvider`, наследуясь от `\Bitrix\Catalog\Product\CatalogProvider`.

Там же переопределяю метод `GetProductData`:

```
class CostumeCatalogProvider extends \Bitrix\Catalog\Product\CatalogProvider
{
    public function GetProductData($params)
    {
        //Получение готового массива цен
        $result = parent::GetProductData($params);
        
        $arResults = $result->getData();
        //Манипуляции с ценами
        foreach ($arResults['PRODUCT_DATA_LIST'] as &$arItemProduct) {
            foreach ($arItemProduct['PRICE_LIST'] as &$arPrice){
                    $arPrice['PRICE'] = round($arPrice['PRICE'] * 101 / 100);
            }
        }

        $result->setData($arResults);
        
        return $result;
     }
}
```

В корзине, в итоге, цена та же, что и была до этого, как будто ничего не пересчиталось. В чем может быть проблема? Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

В $arResult['PRODUCT_DATA_LIST'] есть данные для цикла foreach?

и надо делать просто

```
$result = [
                'BASE_PRICE' => $result['BASE_PRICE'],
                'PRICE' => $calculatedPrice,
                'DISCOUNT_PRICE' => $discountPrice,
                'DISCOUNT_VALUE' => $discountDatas["PERCENT"]."%",
                'DISCOUNT_NAME' => $discountDatas["NAME"],
                'DISCOUNT_PRICE_PERCENT' => $discountPrice
            ] + $result;
```

вместо

```
$arResults = $result->getData();
    //Манипуляции с ценами
    foreach ($arResults['PRODUCT_DATA_LIST'] as &$arItemProduct) {
        foreach ($arItemProduct['PRICE_LIST'] as &$arPrice){
                $arPrice['PRICE'] = round($arPrice['PRICE'] * 101 / 100);
        }
    }

    $result->setData($arResults);
```

Comment: Данные для цикла есть и чтобы добраться до цены нужен цикл иначе там просто нету ключа PRICE как в вашем примере. 

И связано это наверника с тем что вы используете старый класс провайдера от которого происходит наследование.

сейчас это должно происходить от \Bitrix\Catalog\Product\CatalogProvider а не от \CCatalogProductProvider

из документации Битрикс: Класс CCatalogProductProvider устарел с версии 17.5.0 модуля catalog. Используйте \Bitrix\Catalog\Product\CatalogProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изменить $arPrice['BASE_PRICE'], а не $arPrice['PRICE']